# A Doctor Who episode novelization where the Master is his brother

Tags: story-identification, novel, doctor-who

I remember looking at a novelization of a *Doctor Who* episode in a store and reading a scene where it is said that the Master and the Doctor were brothers.  And for a long time I believed they were brothers in the canon of the show.

As I remember, they might have been in an abandoned underground alien city at the time.

Thus I suspect that it might have been a novelization of "Colony in Space", which aired from 10 April to 15 May 1971.

So I wonder if anyone knows whether there is a scene where the Doctor & the Master are claimed to be brothers in a novelization of "Colony in Space" or any other third or fourth doctor serial.

Comment: I believe this was going to be revealed in "The Final Game", which was intended to be the send-off for Jon Pertwee. But due to Delgado's death this story was never filmed (we got "Planet of the Spiders" instead), and I doubt that a novelization was written.

Comment: Are you certain it wasn't an original work (e.g. Virgin New Adventures) rather than a novelization?

Comment: As I remember, I probably read it before 1980, so where there any original Dr. Who novels back then?

Answer (score 2):

The Master's last line in "Planet of Fire" is "Won't you show mercy to your own AAARGH!" and it has long been speculated he was going to say "brother" before being incinerated. ([Tardis Wiki](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_of_Fire_(TV_story)) says John Nathan-Turner said this in response to a question from the director, Fiona Cumming.) This all takes place in his secret lair inside a volcano.

He does *not* say this in the novelization, and it's a Fifth Doctor story rather than Third or Fourth as you suggest. The book was published in 1985, and the serial was in 1984, so it's a bit off from the pre-1980 timeline. But I think this is the most explicit instance of the brother theory.

Answer (score 1):

"Colony In Space" was novelised as *Doctor Who And The Doomsday Weapon.* An online copy is available [here](https://archive.org/details/Doctor_Who_-_Target_Book_023_-_Doctor_Who_and_the_Doomsday_Weapon/page/n5/mode/1up).

A search of the text shows that the word  'brother' does not appear in the book.

At a guess you are conflating two or more books.  Maybe "The Three Doctors", where Omega refers to the Doctor as "brother Time Lord".   That doesn't mean they are literal brothers, just that they have the same origin.